# Getting (Invalid) when adding custom taxonomy of custom post type link in menu

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus

I am getting this message when I am trying to add a link to my menu:

[image: screenshot]

I have created a custom post type and a custom taxonomy

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Portfolio - Custom Post Type
   Plugin URI: 
   Description: 
   Version: 1.0
   Author:
   Author URI: 
   License:
   */
?>
<?php

// ----- Register custom post type ------ //

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_portfolio' );

function create_post_type_portfolio() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Portfolios', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Portfolio', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'job' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Portfolio item' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Portfolio Item' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Portfolio Item' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Portfolio Items' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Portfolio Item' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Portfolio Items' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Portfolio Items found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Portfolio Items found in the Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Portfolio Items'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our Portfolio Items and Portfolio Item specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon'     => plugins_url( 'portfolio.png', __FILE__ ),
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite'       => true,
        'show_ui'       => true,

    );
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args );   
}

// ------------- register taxonomy ----------------- //

// hook into the init action and call create_portfolio_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );

// create Work for the post type "portfolio"
function create_portfolio_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Work', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Work', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Work' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Work' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Work' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Work:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Work' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Work' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Work' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Work Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Work' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'work' )
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'Work', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
}



?>
```

Why ?

Comment: I ran your code and I can't duplicate this. I do not see that box anywhere. Please try to provide more detail. What do you do-- step by step-- to make that box appear?

Comment: who spoke about a box ? it's a custom post type and a custom taxonomy!

Comment: Your ___picture___ is of a _meta box_-- one associated with menus, it looks like-- and your description makes it seem like that box is related to question.

Comment: As I said, "I am getting this message when I am trying to add a link to my menu". I suppose that this explains the rest, isnt't it ? This box is displayed when you add the custom taxonomy to a wordpress menu.

Comment: Got it, but can't figure out _why_. I'll answer if I work it out.

Comment: so much attitude being thrown around!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied my plugin file to a new one .php file and deactivated the old one / activated the new one. Then everything worked successfully. I need to mention that I changed the names of the taxonomies from "Kind" to "Stuff" so I suppose there was an error or something in the database.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the first argument of register_taxonomy not being in "slug" form. I changed mine from "Topics" to "topic" and it worked.
Cite: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Thanks it is helpful for me without changing the taxonomy name.